# UITextField keyboard Issue

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextfield, keyboard-events

I have such a problem: I have a `UITextField` in my `UITableViewCell`. When I tap on that text field -> keyboard appears, but when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> button keyboard don't disappear. I need such a behavior for my text field and keyboard:

1. When I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd> - keyboard must disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Where textField is UITextField in UITableViewCell

Comment: @yozhik, have you set delegate to your textfield? check if that method actually gets called

Answer (score 1):

Implement `textFieldShouldReturn:` method in textField's delegate and call `[textField resignFirstResponder]` there - that will hide keyboard when return key is pressed.

I'm not sure if that will work for 'Esc' as well, but there's no such key on real device anyway so it must not be a problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[txtField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];

txtField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically=YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be an old post but I found it searching for the answer so chances are someone else might so don't shoot me for posting.

Just wanted to add 
don't forget to make the delegate connection in IB for the UITextField

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface Untitled2ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *text;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *text;
@end
```

//m file

```
#import "Untitled2ViewController.h"

@implementation Untitled2ViewController
@synthesize text;

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

In xib file I set: Return Key: Done,   Auto-anabling return key. I also tried without it, and still no reaction. Keyboard don't hides.

Comment: You should edit your question and put details there - answer is not a right place for that + it is too easy to miss your post. still, the mail question - did you set your controller to be text's delegate (either in IB or by code) and does textFieldShouldReturn get called (put breakpoint or log message there to check...)?

Answer (score 0):

Write this code to create UITextLabel

```
    UITextField *username = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 110.0f, 30.0f)]
    [username setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyNext];
    [username setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:username];
```

Now to resign write this code.

```
-(void)resignKeyboard
{
    if([username isEditing])
    {
        [username resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

or this is for anywhere in the view

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```